# Similar commands in Windows CMD?

Tags: cat, xargs

my friends.

I search similar commands (from Linux) in Windows CMD:

```
cat list_link.txt | xargs -n1 -P4 [command]
```

and

```
[command] $(cat link_list.txt)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found similar command line `[command] $(cat link_list.txt)` for Windows CMD:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('type link_list.txt') do [command] %i
```

But `cat list_link.txt | xargs -n1 -P4 [command]` seem harder...

Salute.